# android:calculate value when app in background

Tags: android, background, wifi, background-process, android-wifi

i want to connect wifi hot spot from my app. After connecting my app goes to background. I would like to calculate wifi use time from my app. I use asynctask to connect wifi hot spot and then send my app in background. I have done it successfully. But my problem is to calculate wifi use time and show it . Should i use service to calculate time in background.

```
public class ConnectWifiInAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private String mSsid, mPass, mMode ;

    public ConnectWifiInAsync(String ssid, String pass, String mode){
        super();
        mSsid = ssid ;
        mPass = pass;
        mMode = mode ;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(WifiScanActivity.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Connecting to WiFi. Please Wait.");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        /*connected = true;
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo conn = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence wifi_on = "Connected to " + conn.getSSID();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast responseToast = Toast.makeText(context, wifi_on, duration);
        responseToast.show();*/
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        WifiScanActivity.this.startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        /*WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);*/
        connectToAP(mSsid, mPass, mMode);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple workaround is, when you've sent the app in the background, get the current time and save in SharedPrefs. Also register the Broadcast Receiver `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`. When connection lost. Get the time from sharedPrefs and compare it to the time at startup.

Answer (score 0):

you can use background service to calculate or process your logics.

refer this for more details  http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Answer (score 0):

of course you have to use service to do background calculation. other wise your application instance will be killed by the os and the timer will be stopped, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is the documentation for service, also read [this example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html). inside the service recommended to use a thread to do process your calculations.